# implementing two or more tab panel within same page using boootstrap and django

Tags: jquery, python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

In my django project, i used a for loop to iterate with the following block of code.And hence therefore produced two or more bootstrap panels with each containing a tab panel.

My issue is  that, when the page is seen in a browser, only first panel works.ie, When we click the tabs of second or third panel, the data change occur in the tabs of first panel !.

```
{%for obj in temp%}
    <section id="main-content">
    <section class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">

      <section class="panel"id="{{obj.case_id}}">

          <header class="panel-heading">
                      <span class="label label-success">Case ID as per user submision :</span><span class="label label-inverse">{{obj.case_id}}</span>
                      <span class="tools pull-right">
                          <a href="javascript:;"class="icon-chevron-down"></a>
                          <!-- <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-remove"></a> -->
                      </span>
          </header>
            <div class="panel-body">

                  <section class="panel" >
                          <header class="panel-heading tab-bg-dark-navy-blue ">

                              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                  <li class="active">
                                      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Case_ID</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="">
                                      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">Agency</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="">
                                      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#profile">Officer</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="">
                                      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">Upload date</a>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </header>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                              <div class="tab-content">
                                  <div id="home" class="tab-pane active">
                                      {{obj.case_id}}
                                  </div>
                                  <div id="about" class="tab-pane active">{{obj.case_description}}</div>
                                  <div id="profile" class="tab-pane">{{obj.officer.username}}</div>
                                  <div id="contact" class="tab-pane">{{obj.date_created}}</div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                  </section>
            </div>     
      </section>
    </div>
  </section>
  </section>
    {%endfor%}
```

Any help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to add a unique id to each tab using the iterated object:

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#home-{{obj.case_id}}">Case_ID</a>
```

And in the tab:

```
<div id="home-{{obj.case_id}}" class="tab-pane active">
  {{obj.case_id}}
</div>
```

Of-course you need to apply this solution on all tabs you have.